# How get drawing area in callback for quadview?

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

I need help with Quadview drawing. I know how get the quad using the mouse position, but the problem is get the drawing area in the callback.

I have some code like this:

```
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

..

def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    # mi draw code here
      quad = get_quad(x, y) ???
    # need information of area in pixels or location to select Quad
```

But, I need the area that is drawing to detect the Quad.

how can get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to CoDEmanX, I have the solution:

```
 if not context.space_data.region_quadviews:
        rv3d = bpy.context.space_data.region_3d
    else:
        # verify area 
        if context.area.type != 'VIEW_3D' or context.space_data.type != 'VIEW_3D':
            return
        i = -1
        for region in context.area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                i += 1
                if context.region.id == region.id:
                    break
        else:
            return

        rv3d = context.space_data.region_quadviews[i]
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for.

Comment: For newer versions of Blender, you have to replace `if context.region.id == region.id:` with `if context.region == region:`. Also today I learned `for`-loops in Python can be followed by an `else`-statement.